# deleting from two different tables in single query using postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
DELETE amt
FROM $citables.CI_INBOUND_INVOICE_AMT amt
   , $citemp.invoice_combine ic
WHERE amt.ci_inb_inv_id = ic.TSR_EDI_INV_REF;
```

This is teradata code,need to convert to PostgreSQL. I am getting an error as

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "amt"

LINE 1: DELETE amt
```

Even inner join is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try :

```
DELETE 
FROM $citables.CI_INBOUND_INVOICE_AMT amt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM $citemp.invoice_combine ic 
    WHERE amt.ci_inb_inv_id = ic.TSR_EDI_INV_REF
);
```